# Lower PageSpeed score after setting up Cloudfront as a CDN

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront, pagespeed

[PageSpeed with Cloudfront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTMjW.png)

[PageSpeed without Cloudfront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63VbO.png)

The problem seems to be with just one render blocking element, the stylesheet. But I don't know why from Cloudfront is saying that it need 5 additional round trips and just one from my own server.

All the assets are being hit from Cloudfront with Gzip enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that 
using a **CDN** may incur additional *DNS*/*TLS*/*TCP handshake* roundtrips and that's what google pagespeed is saying

I think it's worth measuring your website performance using other tools like [webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org) that would give you much more insight on what's actually going on and whether it's worth using CDN at all.

Here's a good [article](https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/why-we-dont-use-a-cdn-spdy-ssl/) where authors are exploring their website performance before/after migration to a CDN. You might replicate their research on your own website - their report is very deep and detailed